# Gromov's criterion for quasi-isometry of finitely generated groups

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

In his book "Asymptotic invariants of inifinite groups" (page 4) Gromov gives an equivalence for the quasi-isometry of two finitely generated groups: 
Two finitely generated groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are quasi-isometric if and only if there exist proper actions of $G_1$ and $G_2$ on some locally compact topological space $X$ such that $$$$i) actions commute
$$$$ii) both actions are cocompact
$$$$Given such a topolgical space I can prove that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are quasi-isometric. For the latter implication Gromov gives a short draft:

We consider a space $F$ of all maps from $G_1$ to $G_2$ with the pointwise convergence. Then we take the closure X of the $G_1 \times G_2$ - orbit of our $f \in F$.
Could somebody explain what does it mean that a function $h: G_1 \rightarrow G_2 $ admits pointwise convergence and where does that $f$ function come from (maybe it is supposed to be a sum of orbits of all functions from F)?
Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not saying that any particular function "admits pointwise convergence".  Rather, it's saying to consider the set $F$ of all functions $h:G_1\to G_2$, and to put the topology of pointwise convergence on this set.  This is just the product topology on the set $G_2^{G_1}$ (where I would assume $G_2$ has the discrete topology).

The function $f$ is presumably a quasi-isometry $f:G_1\to G_2$, since you are proving that if such a quasi-isometry exists then there exist actions on a space $X$ with the given properties.